# rJava: failing to load awt.events

Tags: r, rjava

Right now, I try to implement some event methods of awt.events, however I cannot get it to load, since I always get an ClassNotFoundException error.

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
[1] 0
> jEvents <- .jnew("java.awt.event")
Error in .jnew("java.awt.event") : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Edit:

Even if I try a specific class, I get an error message:

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
> jEvents <- .jnew("java.awt.event.ActionEvent")
Error in .jnew("java.awt.event.ActionEvent") : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to instantiate package instead of class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-summary.html

Maybe you are looking for:

```
java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

You can try this one:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
> EVT <- J("java.awt.event.ActionEvent")
> aEVT <- new(EVT, "StringObject", 1001L, "Hello")
> aEVT
[1] "Java-Object{java.awt.event.ActionEvent[ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Hello,when=0,modifiers=] on Str}"
```

You have to call the constructor with given parameters. Note that ActionEvent doesn't have default constructor.

You can find nice source here:

http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#wwjoir

Comment: Thx. I tried a specific class, but still get error messages. See the edit above.

Comment: .oOo. Some new stuff .oOo.